# Relationships between two entities

Tags: sql, relationships, entities

I have a situation:

1. I have a user (creator) who creates events (Each event belongs to one user)
2. Each event can invite other users (participants) (Each user belongs to one event)

So basically, there are two entities (Users and Events), but relationships are not simple.
I mean, user who creates event may be not the same who attends it. A user may be just a participant, but not a creator.

The situation is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583194/multiple-relationships-between-two-entities-is-this-good-practice).

I realised that those relationships are not just many-to-many.

For instance, I may create two tables with two relationships (circular relationship).
To break this circle I need to allow to create a user (participant) without an event by temporarily assigning NULL to it or by creating one more column (Boolean) that indicates whether this user also a creator or not.

But I solved it by creating the third table:

[image]

[Diagram 1](http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120105/Tn4b5738.png)

The third table stores events and their participants.

I also found another way to solve this problem. It involves 4 tables:

1. User (User can be either a creator or a participant)
2. Creator (Creator is user who creates event)
3. Event (Each event belongs to one creator)
4. Participant (Participant is user who takes part in an event, one event has many participants)

These relationships would look like this:

[image]

[Diagram 2](http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120105/5HNVz3cx.png)

Which solution is better?

I liked the one with two tables, but I just needed to dig deeper and find the proper.

Comment: As regards rule 2: "Each user belongs to one event" -- a literal translation would be that a user cannot exist in the database unless they have been associated with exactly one event, can never be associated with more than one event and when they disassociate from that event the user ceases to exist in the database. Is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: You first say "a user creates events" but later say "A user may be just a participant, but not a creator". I think you need to get your rules straightened out!

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is my English, sorry. User does not necessarily should belong to an event. And user can be a participant, a creator or both.

Answer (score 2):

I'd stick to the solution with three tables, as an event is always created by one user. The `EventMember` table solves the n:m relation between `User` and `Event` and is necessary.

Introducing a fourth table `Creator` makes really no sense as it only adds one more `JOIN` to get the creator of an event.

Comment: You haven't addressed the rule "a user who creates event may be not the same who attends it".

Comment: @onedaywhen of course I did. The creator is not automatically inserted into the `EventMember` table and therefore does not attend it by default.

Comment: Ignore: the rule has been stated in three ways and are contradictory so I cannot tell who is correct ;)

Answer (score 1):

Rule as originally stated

> user who creates event may be not the same who attends it. A user may
>   be just a participant, but not a creator.

This seems to indicate that, for each event, a given user may be an attendee or a creator but not both.

However, in comments, the OP later stated:

> user can be a participant, a creator or both.

The following code is based on the earlier assumption (as I made clear in comments); the only adjustment to accommodate the later clarification is to drop the `CHECK` constraint:

```
-- Rule: for each event, a given user may be an attendee or a creator but not both.
-- Rule: each event has zero or one creator.
-- Rule: each event has zero, one or many attendees.
-- General Rule: a table models an entity or a relationship but never both.

CREATE TABLE Users 
(
 user_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
 UNIQUE (user_name)
);

CREATE TABLE Events 
(
 event_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
 UNIQUE (event_name)
);

CREATE TABLE EventCreators 
(
 event_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 creator_user_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
 UNIQUE (event_name),  
 UNIQUE (event_name, creator_user_name),
 FOREIGN KEY (event_name) 
    REFERENCES Events (event_name), 
 FOREIGN KEY (creator_user_name) 
    REFERENCES Users (user_name)    
);

CREATE TABLE EventAttendees
(
 event_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 creator_user_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 attendee_user_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE (event_name, attendee_user_name),  
 FOREIGN KEY (event_name, creator_user_name) 
    REFERENCES EventCreators (event_name, creator_user_name), 
 FOREIGN KEY (attendee_user_name) 
    REFERENCES Users (user_name), 
 CHECK (creator_user_name <> attendee_user_name)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way :

3 tables (like a many to many)

> Table 1 : Users
>
> Table 2 : Users_Events
>
> Table 3 : Events

Table 2 would contain : 
- FK from Table 1

- FK from Table 3
- Attribute that is the nature of the relation (organizer or attendee)...this could be turned into a Relation table and then Table 2 would contain a FK to that table instead
- the date where the relation was initiated (you're bound to need that at some point :) )

So if we say Bob create an event today, and that Sarah and John are added tomorrow as attendees, you would have ( first column is PK for Table 1 and 2) :

> Table 1 1 - Bob 2 - Sarah 3 - John
>
> Table 2 1 - A - Organizer - 05.01.2012 2 - A - Attendee - 06.01.2012 3
>   - A - Attendee - 06.01.2012
>
> Table 3 A - Super new event

if you want Bob to attend the meeting, then a new record must be created in table 2
1 - A - Attendee - 06.01.2012

Then if you need attendees to the event A, you need to join Table 1 2 and 3 and filter on table_2 for "Attendee"

To avoid double entry in case the organizer attends, you may simply have table 2 this way :

Table 2 would contain : 
- FK from Table 1
- FK from Table 3
- Attendee (boolean)
- Organizer (boolean)

This is even more flexible, and for instance if you later need to track who will give a speech in the meeting, you can introduce a new column Speaker without breaking your table. If you foresee many roles, this will not be scalable however