# Relational Database Managment System

Tags: rdbms

Is there a condition in which two database tables can have more than one relationship between them? I saw a data model diagram which has something like that.

Comment: What do you think is the reason for putting a "relationship" in a diagram? What you do you think it tells you? Why didn't the duplicate questions help? An answer that says other than "yes" is just rewriting whatever reference/textbook you should be reading. Please see [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS *Tables* represent relation(ship)s/associations in the relational model & ERM. So-called "relationships" between tables are FKs. A FK says subrows must appear elsewhere (RM), ie an entity participates in a relation(ship)/association (ERM).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple relationships between two entities, is this good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583194/multiple-relationships-between-two-entities-is-this-good-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when a primary key from one table is used as a foreign key in another for several times. For instance, you may have a table "people" and a table "books" where books table will have fields writer_id, editor_id (among others) all referencing the primary key from people table.